# Intermittent linker and build errors, while using realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, linker-errors, xcode10

I am using the realm cocoapods version

```
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 2.8.1' //pod 'RealmSwift'
```

in my one of old project project and linking gives me lot of errors. Such as:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

  "realm::_impl::TransactLogEncoder::select_table(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long const*)", referenced from:
      realm::_impl::TransactReverser::select_table(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long const*) in transact_log_handler.o
  "realm::SlabAlloc::reset_free_space_tracking()", referenced from:
      realm::Group::reset_free_space_tracking() in transact_log_handler.o
  "realm::SharedGroup::commit_and_continue_as_read()", referenced from:
      realm::_impl::SharedGroupFriend::commit_and_continue_as_read(realm::SharedGroup&) in transact_log_handler.o
  "realm::util::StringBuffer::reallocate(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      realm::util::StringBuffer::reserve(unsigned long) in transact_log_handler.o
  "realm::BinaryColumn::get_at(unsigned long, unsigned long&) const", referenced from:
      realm::BinaryIterator::get_next() in transact_log_handler.o
  "realm::SharedGroup::grab_read_lock(realm::SharedGroup::ReadLockInfo&, realm::VersionID)", referenced from:
      bool realm::SharedGroup::do_advance_read<realm::_impl::NullInstructionObserver>(realm::_impl::NullInstructionObserver*, realm::VersionID, realm::_impl::History&) in transact_log_handler.o
      bool realm::SharedGroup::do_advance_read<(anonymous namespace)::TransactLogValidator>((anonymous namespace)::TransactLogValidator*, realm::VersionID, realm::_impl::History&) in transact_log_handler.o
      bool realm::SharedGroup::do_advance_read<(anonymous namespace)::KVOTransactLogObserver>((anonymous namespace)::KVOTransactLogObserver*, realm::VersionID, realm::_impl::History&) in transact_log_handler.o
      bool realm::SharedGroup::do_advance_read<(anonymous namespace)::TransactLogObserver>((anonymous namespace)::TransactLogObserver*, realm::VersionID, realm::_impl::History&) in transact_log_handler.o
```

This seems related to: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2393

So I tried this

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
pod install
```

to resolve the problem but unfortunately its not working.  Can anyone suggest me solution for this ? Any help will be thankful.

Comment: Did you update your project to a newer version of Swift when you opened it in Xcode? That's a pretty old version of RealmSwift so perhaps your Swift and Realm versions are out of sync.

Comment: @Jay I've tried with latest version too, as you can see its commented. Its getting same error. :(

Comment: Try using cocoa pods to update your app, then let us know what the errors are if any